# Spring RabbitMQ tutorial results in Connection Refused error

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm an experienced Java programmer and am trying out Spring Rabbit MQ for the first time.

I followed the messaging-rabbitMQ tutorial **exactly** using Maven.
http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

I am running on CentOS as a user account.

When I ran the application at the very end of the tutorial with `java -jar target/gs-messaging-rabbitmq-0.1.0.jar`, I got the following Connection Refused error. Can someone help?

```
prompt> java -jar target/gs-messaging-rabbitmq-0.1.0.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

2015-05-13 11:49:44.833  INFO 26218 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application v0.1.0 on minerva-02-33.gbcl.net with PID 26218 (/home/ccpm/test/spring_rabbitmq/target/gs-messaging-rabbitmq-0.1.0.jar started by ccpm in /home/ccpm/test/spring_rabbitmq)
2015-05-13 11:49:44.912  INFO 26218 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@8146158: startup date [Wed May 13 11:49:44 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-05-13 11:49:45.863  INFO 26218 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a886eed] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-05-13 11:49:46.397  INFO 26218 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-05-13 11:49:46.404  INFO 26218 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-05-13 11:49:46.433 ERROR 26218 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:441)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1065)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:615)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:199)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Waiting five seconds...
2015-05-13 11:49:51.437  WARN 26218 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2015-05-13 11:49:51.437  INFO 26218 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-13 11:49:51.441 ERROR 26218 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:441)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1065)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:615)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:199)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where is RabbitMQ server installed? Is it on the same server?

Comment: @Leon: I don't know. I just simply followed the instructions in that tutorial. Did the tutorial steps include a server?

Comment: No it didn't... full answer incoming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not have RabbitMQ server installed. Luckily this is pretty easy to do. You mentioned you are using CentOS, here you can download RabbitMQ server: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

There are a couple of steps you will need to follow, including installing Erlang.

The Spring example assumes you already know a bit about using a message broker. This is in itself a technology you will need to use, like when you had to learn to use a database or an operating system.

Comment: The tutorial webpage at `http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/` clearly says at the top: "This guide walks you through the process of setting up a RabbitMQ AMQP server that publishes and subscribes to messages." Why would it say that and not set up the server when I complete all the steps?

Comment: I think it is a wording problem. The tutorial shows you how to create a publisher and a consumer for RabbitMQ

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Maybe because there's parts of the docs missing? It happens. I'd have been suspicious when it said that installation instructions were below and then there weren't any.

Comment: Yes; you have to install rabbitmq itself. The Spring application is simply a client that uses the broker. I have opened [an issue against the guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/issues/6). Refer to the [rabbitmq site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for how to install the server.

Comment: @GaryRussell: After I install RabbitMQ, how do I "connect" the Spring library to that RabbitMQ server? I don't see anything saying "localhost" or other IP address.

Comment: Fixed the guide via https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/commit/ad1fcf37ea41c21253336f073a73cb58004c79d3

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 you will need to provide an ConnectionFactory bean with the properties to connect to your configured server

Comment: @Leon: Thanks. Is this ConnectionFactory bean in the source examples on that webpage? There are two Java classes, `Application.java` and `Receiver.java`, on the webpage. I don't see any mention of connection parameters.

Comment: No it is not, the example uses a default bean provided by Spring. You can create a bean of this http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html

Comment: Spring Boot (convention over configuration) sets the defaults to `localhost:5672` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitProperties.java It assumes the rabbitmq server is on localhost on the default port. See the [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) about how to configure the properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I'll post my answer anyway as it addresses an issue with this particular step of the Spring tutorial that the other answer doesn't.

If you are using the `docker-compose.yml` file specified in the Spring tutorial to launch a RabbitMQ server in a Docker container you might run into the same issue I had connecting to it, which I outlined in this question;

[Docker image for Spring/RabbitMQ tutorial results in connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44804018/8215811)

After coming back to it a couple of days later though I managed to find the solution;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44882772/8215811

The Spring tutorial unfortunately does not clarify that you need to configure connection information when choosing using the `docker-compose` file over the manual installation of RabbitMQ, which is unfortunate as the Docker method seems easier and more straightforward.